# How can I get the selected time from my timepicker and assign it to a TextBox value?

Tags: c#, jquery

I am trying to get the selected time from my timepicker then assign it as the value in the @Html.TextBox() value attritibute.  I’ve tried using this line of code:  @(timeValue) = timepicker('getTime')… but it doesn’t store a value in the timeValue variable.  Then I tried timeValue = timepicker('getTime') and get an error message about datepicker not being defined.  The code below works fine except for the part where I need to get the selected value from my timepicker.

How can I get the selected time from my timepicker and assign it to a TextBox value?
Thanks for any help with this one.

```
            string date = "date" + course.Index.ToString();
            string time = "time" + course.Index.ToString();
            string timeValue = "";

                                 <script type="text/javascript">




                                     $(function () {
                                         $('input[name= @(date) ]').datepicker();
                                         $('input[name=@(time)]').timepicker({});
                                         @(timeValue) = timepicker('getTime');
                                     });


    </script> 


            string day = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
         @Html.TextBox(name: time, value: timeValue, htmlAttributes: new { id = time, @class = "TextBoxCss" })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign javascript to razor variable. Instead use jquery to assign the value.

But first of all, i think you are not using the @Html.TextBox right.

Try,

```
@Html.TextBox("time", null, new {id = "time", @class = "TextBoxCss"})
```

Then jquery,

```
 var timeValue = timepicker('getTime');
 $("#time").val(timeValue);
```

**Edited:**

Use jquery, ajax form serialize. E.g.

```
$("#sendTimeButton").on("click", function () { // or use on form submit

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", // or GET
                url: "@Url.Action("Edit", "ControllerName")",

                data: $("#myForm").serialize(), //you can use json also JSON.Stringtify

                cache: false,
                success: function () {


                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
        });
```

You can also use an array:

```
var timeArray = new Array();
$(".TextBoxCss").each(function(){
   timeArray.push($(this).val())   // loop through all text boxes with class "TextBoxCss"
});
```

Then the data part is as such:

```
data: {times: timeArray},  // "times" refer to the argument in your controller
```

Then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id,  string[] times)
```

Comment: but I want to eventually access this in my controller.  How can I pass the selected date to my controller using this method?

Comment: I should've mentioned that the textbox is in a loop.  I tried using the id of the text box but it wouldn't work for looping them...I'm incrementing the name attribute in the loop.  I want to access the selected value in my controller so I thought I had to use razor variables in some way.  How can I get this.. $('input[name=@(time)]').val(timeValue)...to my controller?

Answer (score 0):

So I kept the code very much like my original post....

```
   string date = "date" + course.Index.ToString();
    string time = "time" + course.Index.ToString();


                  <script type="text/javascript">

                 $(function () {
                 $('input[name= @(date) ]').datepicker();
                 $('input[name=@(time)]').timepicker({});

                                     });


               </script> 


            string day = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();



         @Html.TextBox(name: time, value: "Set Time", htmlAttributes: new { id = time, @class = "TextBoxCss" })
         @Html.TextBox(name: date, value: day, htmlAttributes: new { id = date, @class = "TextBoxCss" })
```

Then in my controller I'm doing this and I can create a loop to iterate through all texboxes in the list:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id,  FormCollection formCollection)
    {

        String theTimes = Convert.ToString(formCollection["time0"]);
```

}